# Behavior of Passing Nullable<T> into a Generic Method that accepts T?

Tags: c#, oop, nullable

I am wondering what the behavior of passing a `Nullable<int>` type to a generic method that accepts a `T?` (another `Nullable<int>` type). Here is the code in question:

```
int? myNullableParameter = 8;
MyGenericMethod(myNullableParameter);

void MyGenericMethod<T>(T? parameter)
{
    //Do Something with parameter
    Console.WriteLine($"{parameter}");
}
```

As this compiles fine here is the confusion. I am setting the type of myNullableParameter to `Nullable<int>`. Then I pass this type into the parameterized generic method as `Nullable<T>`. However, the type of the parameter is also a `T?` which gets resolved from the compiler to a `Nullable<T>`. So is it a `Nullable<Nullable<int>>`? Or does the compiler simply ignore this second `Nullable<T>` and keep the parameter inside the method as a `Nullable<int>`?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the language-version of C# you're using. e.g. C# 9.0 vs. 8.0 changed the rules.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Was the result `Nullable<int>` or `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` (or some third thing).  In general, the compiler is going to be better at telling you what happens when you compile some code you've already written than asking strangers on the internet.

Comment: @Servy How would I do that? I printed the following and it just gave me System.Int32:

`Console.WriteLine($"{parameter.GetType()}");`
System.Int32

Comment: @KarlGardner You'd want to use `typeof` as `GetType` will box the value, changing the result.  Or  you could hover over the method and let the VS tooltip tell you, or return it and see what the type it, etc.

Comment: @Servy  Ahh, forgot about that. 

So with the Method signature of this: `void MyGenericMethod<T>(T? parameter)` I have the following code:

`Console.WriteLine($"{typeof(T?)}");`

Doesn't exactly print the type passed in but that prints the following so maybe it ignores it:

System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]

Answer (score 1):

(My answer assumes you're using C# 9.0 or later)

> I am wondering what the behavior of passing a `Nullable<int>` type to a generic method that accepts a `T?` (another `Nullable<int>` type).

Methinks you have a misconception; from here it looks like you think/understand/believe that when an *unconstrained* generic type `T` is annotated as `T?` then it means C#+CLR will handle *value-typed `T`* type-arguments as `Nullable<T>` and *reference-typed `T`* type-arguments as `[AllowNull]/[MaybeNull]`, including somehow marshalling non-`null` value-types between `T?` and `T`.

[However the truth is... *it doesn't*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations).

Since C# 9.0, the generic-type syntax `T?` (**when `T` is unconstrained**) just means that:

- "*If `T` is a reference-type, then at-this-point, this T is *possibly-null*, i.e. `[AllowNull]/[MaybeNull]`*"
- "*If `T` is a `Nullable<U>`, then at-this-point, `T` *could* be `null`*"

  - i.e. `nullableStruct.HasValue == false`
  - Similarly, if a type `T` (*not* a `T?`) appears in the same scope, then that denotes a non-`null` `Nullable<T>` (i.e. `value.HasValue == true`).
- "*If `T` is a value-type (*and not `Nullable<U>`*), then this T is **a non-nullable `T`** value-type*".

  - This one stands out like a sore thumb and is an ugly new *wart* on the C# language. *le sigh*.

---

#### A demonstration:

Consider this method:

```
void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<T>( T? nullableTee, T notNullableTee ) // <-- T is unconstrained here
{
    // etc
}
```

##### Case 1: Non-nullable-reference-type `T := String`

If we specify `T = String` then:

- The `nullableTee` parameter retains its `?` annotation, so it becomes `String?`.
- The `notNullableTee` parameter represents (non-nullable) `String`.

So we have `void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<String>( String? nullableTee, String notNullableTee )` such that `nullableTee` accepts a maybe-`null` `String` reference and `notNullableTee` does not.

...so far, so good.

##### Case 2: Nullable-reference-type `T := String?`

If we specify `T = String?`, then the `nullableTee` parameter *won't* be `String??`, but instead the annotations collapse down to `String?`

...while `T notNullableTee` turns into `String? notNullableTee`.

So we have `void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<String?>( String? nullableTee, String? notNullableTee )` such that `nullableTee` accepts a maybe-`null` `String` reference - and `notNullableTee` is actually quite nullable.

<sub>...feeling awkward yet?</sub>

##### Case 3: (Non-nullable) value-type `T := Int32`

If we specify `T = Int32`, then the `?` annotation on `nullableTee`'s type ***is a lie*** because its *static type* remains `Int32` *and not `Nullable<Int32>`*.

- So we have `void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<Int32>( Int32 nullableTee, Int32 notNullableTee )` such that `nullableTee` *cannot* accept a `Nullable<Int32>`, despite the `?` annotation, but at least `notNullableTee` is accurately-named once again...
- <sub>I've overheard people saying that in-light of this, the `?` annotation should be interpreted as "maybe-`default(T)`" and not "maybe-`null`" - but those people live a in bubble.</sub>

##### Case 4: Nullable-value-type `T := Nullable<Int32>` (aka `Int32?`)

If we specify `T = Nullable<Int32>` (aka `Int32?` or `int?`), then the `?` annotation on `nullableTee`'s type is basically ignored by everything now - and all `T` values are nullable too; so now we have `void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<Nullable<Int32>>( Nullable<Int32> nullableTee, Nullable<Int32> notNullableTee )`

...so our `notNullableTee` is a *liar-liar-type-system-on-fire*.

---

Here's what happens when you run such a program with those type-parameter arguments:

```
void Main()
{
    AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<String >( null, "a"  );
    AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<String?>( null, null );
    
    AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<Int32  >(  123,  456 );
    AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<Int32? >( null, null );
}

static void AcceptsAllegedlyNullableT<T>( T? nullableTee, T notNullableTee ) // <-- T is unconstrained here
{
    Console.WriteLine( "------------------------------------------" );
    
    Type staticType   = typeof(T);
    Type runtimeType1 = nullableTee   ?.GetType();
    Type runtimeType2 = notNullableTee?.GetType();
    
    Console.WriteLine( "Runtime value of nullableTee   : " + ( nullableTee   ?.ToString() ?? "null" ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "Runtime value of notNullableTee: " + ( notNullableTee?.ToString() ?? "null" ) );
    
    Console.WriteLine( "Static-type of nullableTee   : " + typeof(T) .FullName );
    Console.WriteLine( "Static-type of notNullableTee: " + typeof(T?).FullName );
    
    Console.WriteLine( "Runtime-type of nullableTee   : " + ( nullableTee   ?.GetType().FullName ?? "null" ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "Runtime-type of notNullableTee: " + ( notNullableTee?.GetType().FullName ?? "null" ) );
    
    Console.WriteLine( "------------------------------------------" );
}
```

Console output:

```
Runtime value of nullableTee   : null
Runtime value of notNullableTee: a
Static-type of nullableTee   : System.String
Static-type of notNullableTee: System.String
Runtime-type of nullableTee   : null
Runtime-type of notNullableTee: System.String
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
Runtime value of nullableTee   : null
Runtime value of notNullableTee: null
Static-type of nullableTee   : System.String
Static-type of notNullableTee: System.String
Runtime-type of nullableTee   : null
Runtime-type of notNullableTee: null
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
Runtime value of nullableTee   : 123
Runtime value of notNullableTee: 456
Static-type of nullableTee   : System.Int32
Static-type of notNullableTee: System.Int32
Runtime-type of nullableTee   : System.Int32
Runtime-type of notNullableTee: System.Int32
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
Runtime value of nullableTee   : null
Runtime value of notNullableTee: null
Static-type of nullableTee   : System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
Static-type of notNullableTee: System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
Runtime-type of nullableTee   : null
Runtime-type of notNullableTee: null
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It seems like making a type parameter nullable (T?) is redundant if a Nullable<T> is passed in to the type! Meaning the compiler ignores the ? in case4 with the nullableTee parameter since the type is already passed in as nullable!

Comment: @KarlGardner Right - but keep-in-mind this only applies to _unconstrained_ type-parameters; whereas once you specify a `T : class` or `T : struct` constraint then sanity returns.

Comment: The sad thing is that because the CLR supports reified generics (unlike Java's type-erased generics - which is why C# supports value-types for generic-params when Java doesn't) is that I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to add support for how-it-should-work - but we'll see...

Comment: It's also kinda a surprise to look-back and see that nullable-reference-types are still a very recent addition to C# - they only launched in .NET Core 3.1 a few years ago.